# File watcher Tailwind PhpStorm not working

Tags: phpstorm, tailwind-css, webstorm, file-watcher

I'm having a problem file watching Tailwind with a file watcher but also with the following command:

```
npx tailwindcss  style.css AMP-IT.nl/output.css --watch
```

It doesn't notice any changes to `index.php` it does watch `style.css`. I did include `index.php` in my Tailwind config file.

I like to just have a file watcher so when I save it makes the classes. If I want to make the classes I have to use `npx tailwindcss build style.css -o AMP-IT.nl/output.css --verbose` which does work.

File structure:

[image]

File watcher that doesn't work:

[image]

Comment: Your File Watcher watches CSS files ONLY -- just as it is configured. To watch multiple file types you have to: 1) Change "File Type" to `Any` 2) "Scope" -- you have to define custom one that includes those files: use `...` and create one, then select it here in the File Watcher.

Comment: 3) You cannot use `--watch` param in File Watcher -- it makes no sense. With `--watch` it will keep running checking for changes. But IDE File Watcher is not for that: it's run and done. The IDE will execute it when needed. I suggest you check the docs first.

Comment: Thank you LazyOne sadly i did try it without and sometimes it works but most times my file watcher times out.

Comment: *"...but most times my file watcher times out."* Sadly that tells me nothing. 1) How long does it normally it takes to compile your css files when run the command in system terminal? 2)I assume you use exactly the same command in File Watcher as well, right?

Comment: With scss or bootstrap compiling it takes like maybe a second. Now it takes 5/6 seconds before it times out. im using the same command but it doenst work :( maybe you have an example on how to set up the file watcher. Right now im using `npx tailwindcss build -i style.css -o output.css` it works but i have to spam ctrl + s because the first time my file watcher times out.

Comment: first it says checking file watcher. then it times out. Then when i press it again it says running tailwind and it works, // Tailwind is what i call my file watcher btw.

Comment: 1) `npx tailwindcss build -i style.css -o output.css`. The Program here is `npx` and `tailwindcss build -i style.css -o output.css` should go into the Arguments field. 2) You can untick "Auto-save edited files..." option. Otherwise it will try to run the File Watcher after a 1-2 secs delay. Better to run it on Save only. Better post you current File Watcher config.

Comment: 3) How long this program takes when you run it in system terminal? If it takes 5 secs there and 5-6 secs in the IDE then it is the same.  4) AFAIK the IDE has some sort of timeout for File Watchers execution but I'm not sure how long it is and where to change it. Post a screenshot of your timeout message. It may give some hints. 5) Sadly I do not use tailwind myself and cannot give you a working File Watcher example. But the common sense tells me that it should just work, just like sass or less compilation.

Comment: This is the exact settings i have right now and in the terminal it only takes 300ms. I stopped trying and am now just developing my site with a CDN and when im done ill just build it once. Thanks for you're help tho!